# How can a wire have 0 conductivity and 0 resistance?

Tags: resistance, heat, wire

First post but lurking for over a year

I bought some cheap heating pads on EBay a long time ago. 4v wouldn't get all 5 in parallel hot enough and 8v was unbearably hot so they went in the pile of crap for awhile.

I pulled them out to see if I could regulate the voltage with a DC voltage regulator that included a 10k potentiometer (which doesn't matter because the regulator circuit allowed it to work for my test). It did pretty well except for the need to be EXTREMELY precise while turning the pot.

The wire for the heating pads seem to be sandwiched between what was sold as carbon fiber cloth. There is a 2 wire"loop" which returns to the other side of the battery. I couldn't tell if they connected inside each pad or only at the termination pad,so I tore one apart. The wire inside was so fine and the "carbon fiber" so tightly glued I never found out about the connection.  I did salvage about 1 ft of the wire to test it. The wire is about 1mm thick with some type of thread in it about like a human hair. I connected the wire negative to positive on a 1.2v AA cell, a 3.7v cell and a 7.4v battery pack.  All fully charged. No spark. UnNo heated wire. No heated batteries. No ohm reading on the wire itself. No battery discharge at all after 15 minutes. I took the hair sized filament out...same thing.

What did I do wrong?

Okay. To answer some questions. If I connect a wire from positive to negative on an 8 volt 4A battery the power should go somewhere. Heat the wire, drain the battery, short the battery...what else? Energy can't disappear.

Comment: I don't see anything here that indicates zero resistance.

Comment: Most likely you are seeing infinite, not zero, resistance. Possibly because of transparent varnish or lacquer or similar coating on the wire.

Comment: "*No ohm reading on the wire itself.*" You need to write clear technical information. Does this mean 0 Ω or \$ \infty \$ Ω.

Comment: No heated wire with 8v input for a 1mm wire?

Comment: If infinate resistance wouldn't I have heat somewhere

Comment: Did you check Brian Drummond's comment? Could you add pictures?

Comment: @PaulPease No. Infinite resistance implies zero current flow. Zero current flow means no power consumed. No power consumed means no heat.

Comment: I already destroyed the heating pad. I also cleaned it with 90% isopropyl alcohol and pulled the white hair-like fiber off. I agree with the infinite resistance point of view because the meter actually reads "1" in every setting but what metal has infinite resistance in 1 ft at 1mm diameter?

Comment: Also... How could it have worked in the pad then? Same adhesive all around it.

Comment: your second paragraph indicates unclear thinking ... if 4 V is not warm enough and 8 V is too hot, then why would you not try something in between?

Comment: Open circuit on a 2s 18650 battery?  I been there done that few years ago. Those fires dont go out easy

Comment: I have a 5v and 6v fixed boost converter but I really just wanted to see what was inside. Then I could just make one the size and shape i wanted with a 1209 temp controller and a pot if I wanted

Comment: The thing worked at 8V and got very hot. Now, it doesn't anymore. You're right the wire resistance doesn't change to infinity randomly/suddenly. So, carefully run along the steps you did after it worked till it didnt. My guesses are you try to connect to lacquered wires (Did you check Brian Drummond's comment?) or you applied too much current the wire got burned, causing it to get way higher resistance or even burnt to an open circuit

Comment: @PaulPease No, an **open circuit** on any battery will not cause a fire. An open circuit means that no current flows. I think you have some really fundamental problems with the basic concepts in this area.

Comment: Conductivity is defined as 1/resistance, so 0 of both would be pretty hard.

Comment: I meant short circuit.  Sorry, answering too many things at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did salvage about 1 ft of the wire to test it. The wire is about 1mm thick with some type of thread in it about like a human hair. I connected the wire negative to positive on a 1.2v AA cell, a 3.7v cell and a 7.4v battery pack. All fully charged. No spark. UnNo heated wire. No heated batteries. No ohm reading on the wire itself. No battery discharge at all after 15 minutes. I took the hair sized filament out...same thing.

If you can't even read the resistance on a meter, you effectively do not have a complete circuit, so no surprise you can't get it to heat up.  The wire may be broken, you may not have good contact, or it may be laminated to prevent contact.  Time to troubleshoot and figure out why you don't have a circuit.

> If I connect a wire from positive to negative on an 8 volt 4A battery the power should go somewhere.

From what you've said above, you didn't actually connect the wires, so no power goes through the wire.